# katalon test case parameterize with variable

Tags: api, katalon-studio

i would like post different API body every time the test case run.

i have set the variable at POST object
e.g. testID default value test0001
then the HTTP body as below, test and verify passed.
{
“drugId”: “$testID”,
}

what syntax/command i can use in test case like parameterize test step, so first time test case run
drugId = test0001
second time test case run, it will be
drugId = test0002

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP body should be something like

```
{ 
  “drugId”: “${testID}” 
}
```

And your request in code should look something like this

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('requestObject',[('testID'): 'test0001']))
```

where `requestObject` is your request saved in the Object Repository.

**Implementation**

Now, if you want to iterate this 10 times, you can do the following:

1. create a new test case called "callee" with the following content

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('requestObject',[('testID'): testID]))
```

2. create another test case called "caller" with the following content

```
String test = "test000"
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase("callee"), ["testID":"${test+i.toString()}"], FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)
}
```

3. run the "caller" test

Comment: on second test case execution, the id does not auto increase, it post the same ID.

Comment: I haven't included id incrementation yet. You need a way for the test to know this is execution no 1, 2, 3... Do you have this figured out or are you just manually repeating test?

Comment: because this is json POST then stored to database directly, ID is unique, where i have another test case, when same ID posted, then error throw by API response , test case detected the message and passed. the code is like this: WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(response, 400)
assertThat(response.getResponseText()).contains('drugId already exists')

Comment: i run the test, it is the same as earlier test case, first execution then 10 records posted. second execution then no record posted because the same ID already used and being posted during first execution. what i mean is the test automatically knew previous execution ID then on next new execution, skip that one and increase it by +1. am i need to store previous result somewhere?